# CAS with Spring Security - Redirect loop

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, cas, jasig

I've been configuring SSO solution using CAS for existing application with Spring Security integrated. I went through many answers on Stackoverflow but unfortunately anyone could help me. Could you please assist me with this issue from perspective of my configuration? Thank you in advance!

Here is my core security configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

<description>This context sets up security configurations of the core module.</description>

<!-- Enabled support for @Secured annotations on Spring bean methods -->
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"
                                 access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"/>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="casAuthenticationProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>    

<bean id="casAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="authenticationUserDetailsService">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
            <constructor-arg ref="userDetailsService"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties"/>
    <property name="ticketValidator">
        <bean class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator">
            <constructor-arg index="0" value="https://localhost:8443/cas"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="key" value="an_id_for_this_auth_provider_only"/>
</bean>

<security:http entry-point-ref="casEntryPoint">
    <security:custom-filter ref="casFilter" position="CAS_FILTER"/>
</security:http>

<bean id="casFilter" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="casEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginUrl" value="https://localhost:8443/cas/login"/>
    <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties"/>
</bean>

<bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="casEntryPoint"/>
</bean>

<bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">        
    <property name="service" value="http://localhost:8080/myApp/j_spring_cas_security_check"/>
    <property name="sendRenew" value="false"/>
</bean>

<!-- Service that retrieves UserDetails from DB for authentication -->
<bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.xxx.yyy.core.security.userdetails.DefaultUserDetailsService">
    <property name="pmUserService" ref="pmUserService"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource" id="randomSaltSource">
    <property name="userPropertyToUse" value="salt"/>
</bean>


<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <property name="decisionVoters">
        <!-- At least one voter must agree that the user can access a resource -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
            <!-- Override the default is 'ROLE_' prefix for role names -->
            <property name="rolePrefix">
                <util:constant static-field="com.xxx.yyy.core.security.SecurityConstants.AUTHORITY_PREFIX"/>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

...and additional security module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring- util-3.0.xsd">

<description>This context sets up security configurations of the web module</description>

<import resource="web-security-urls.xml"/>

<!-- Spring Security Filter Chain -->
<bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <security:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/**"
                               filters="securityContextPersistenceFilter,
                                        logoutFilter,
                                        authenticationFilter,
                                        anonymousAuthenticationFilter,
                                        exceptionTranslationFilter,
                                        filterSecurityInterceptor"/>
    </security:filter-chain-map>
</bean>

<!-- Responsible for propagation of SecurityContext on ThreadLocal from HttpSession -->
<bean id="securityContextPersistenceFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter"/>

<!-- define the logout exit point -->
<bean id="logoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
    <!-- go to login page upon successful logout -->
    <constructor-arg value="/"/>
    <!-- Classes that get run when a user logs out -->
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_logout"/>
</bean>

<!-- Enable expression evaluation for Spring Security -->
<bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator">
    <constructor-arg ref="filterSecurityInterceptor"/>
</bean>
```

And also we have separate module `web-security-urls.xml` where `o.s.s.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor` is configured to declare secure URLs

Comment: The issue has been resolved! Seems, that I just had to replace `authenticationFilter` with `casFilter` in `filterChainProxy` bean

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the exact problem, but looks like you might be missing a filter url here due to which you are getting a infinite redirect loop.

```
<bean id="casFilter" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
</bean>
```

you can add the filter url to filter only a particular url pattern

```
<property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_cas_security_check"/>
```

This helped me when i was stuck in the same type of problem.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! However, unfortunately, it didn't help much :(

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you still have this problem. I was facing the same and it is nerve-wracking. The issue of infinite redirect results when `CasAuthenticationFilter` is not able to determine if the incoming URL ( redirected URL from CAS server ) needs authentication.

```
  if (!requiresAuthentication(request, response)) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

        return;
    }
```

The requires authentication checks if the request is identified as "filterable" URL.

```
 private static final class FilterProcessUrlRequestMatcher implements RequestMatcher {
    private final String filterProcessesUrl;

    private FilterProcessUrlRequestMatcher(String filterProcessesUrl) {
        Assert.hasLength(filterProcessesUrl, "filterProcessesUrl must be specified");
        Assert.isTrue(UrlUtils.isValidRedirectUrl(filterProcessesUrl), filterProcessesUrl + " isn't a valid redirect URL");
        this.filterProcessesUrl = filterProcessesUrl;
    }

    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String uri = request.getRequestURI();
        int pathParamIndex = uri.indexOf(';');

        if (pathParamIndex > 0) {
            // strip everything after the first semi-colon
            uri = uri.substring(0, pathParamIndex);
        }

        if ("".equals(request.getContextPath())) {
            return uri.endsWith(filterProcessesUrl);
        }

        return uri.endsWith(request.getContextPath() + filterProcessesUrl);
    }
}
```

With a context path , the check basically checks if the "service URL" ends with `request.getContextPath() + filterProcessesUrl`

So, URL in the "service" property of ServiceProperties object needs to match to what is provided in filterProcessesUrl.
For example :

```
<bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
    <property name="service"
        value="https://localhost:9444/SpringSecurity2.5/tbr/j_spring_cas_security_check" />
    <property name="sendRenew" value="false" />

</bean>

<bean id="casFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
    </property>
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/tbr/j_spring_cas_security_check"/>

</bean>
```

Note the matching pattern for **/tbr/j_spring_cas_security_check** in both these configurations.

Comment: And to add, the notion of service URL in case of spring-security+CAS works differently than a "normal" CAS client filtered web application. Spring security maintains a request URL in a cache(session object) before attempting any authentication scheme (BASIC, FORM BASED, CAS , X.509 etc). When the authentication is successful , it fetches the original request from the cache and attempts a client redirect(302). So a service URL is ACTUALLY not the URL that you map in a spring controller, but simply one that is recognized by CAS Filter

Comment: `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler                         (SavedRequest) session.getAttribute(SAVED_REQUEST);                   String targetUrl = savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();                                        getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);`